# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded & Reactive Forms

Tags: forms, angular, stack, max, call

I'm getting the RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and I don't understand why. I'm using Socket.IO & Angular 2. I'm making a website where you can create quizzes, which can have multiple questions, which can have multiple answers and I'm using forms to achieve that.

HTML for Quiz:

```html
<table class=pageTable align=center border="1px">
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" align=center>
    <!-- we will place our fields here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit Quiz</button>

    <!-- Quiz Title -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quiz Title</label><br/>
        <input type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control"><br/>
        <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.title.valid">
            Title must be between 5-30 characters.
        </small>
        <br/><select class="Quiz-access-dropdown" formControlName="access">
            <option *ngFor="let access of accessArray">{{access.option}}</option>
        </select>
        <br/><small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.access.valid">
            Select a quiz access level.
        </small>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <!-- List of Questions -->
    <div formArrayName="questions" align=center>
        <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let question of myForm.controls.questions.controls; let i=index" class="Question-panel">
            <div class="Question-panel-title">
                <span>Question {{i + 1}}:</span>

                <question [group]="myForm.controls.questions.controls[i]"></question>
                <span class="x-button" *ngIf="myForm.controls.questions.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeQuestion(i)">x</span>
                <br/><small *ngIf="!question.controls.questionText.valid">
                    Question must be at least 10 characters.
                </small>
                <!-- List of question types -->
                <br/><label>Question type:</label>
                <select class="Question-type-dropdown" formControlName="types">
                    <option *ngFor="let type of typesArray">{{type.option}}</option>
                </select>
                <br/><small *ngIf="!question.controls.types.valid">
                    Select a question type.
                </small>
            </div>

            <!-- List of Answers -->
            <div class="Question-panel-content">
                <div formArrayName="answers" align=center>
                    <div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let answer of question.controls.answers.controls; let j=index">
                        <span>Answer {{j + 1}}:</span>
                        <answer [group]="question.controls.answers.controls[j]"></answer>
                        <select class="Question-answer-correct-dropdown" formControlName="correctAnswer">
                            <option *ngFor="let correct of correctAnswerArray">{{correct.option}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="x-button" *ngIf="question.controls.answers.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAnswer(i, j)">x</span>
                        <br/><small *ngIf="!answer.controls.answerText.valid">
                            Answer must be at least 4 characters.
                        </small>
                        <br/><small *ngIf="!answer.controls.correctAnswer.valid">
                            Answer must either be correct or incorrect.
                        </small>
                    </div>
                    <br/><button (click)="addAnswer(i)" class="template-button">Add answer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <button (click)="addQuestion()" class="template-button">Add question</button>
</form>
```

HTML for Question:

```html
<div [formGroup]="questionForm" class="Question-panel-title-input">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="questionText">
     </div>
</div>
```

HTML for Answer:

```html
<div [formGroup]="answerForm" class="Question-Answer-panel-input">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="answerText">
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that when I try to send the form from my client to the server, I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded error:

```html
save() {
    socket.emit('quiz', this.myForm);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!